# Save Variable of LookUpOrderedRow

Tags: query, dataextensions

i have two DataExtensions, for Example "Customers" and "Cars" and i want to output a field in Cars which is reference for a field in "Customers".

```
Customers
=========
ID | Name | Email | Cars
....................VW Polo
....................Ford Fiesta


Cars
==============
IDcar | Wheels
VW Polo | Wheel XY
Ford Fiesta Wheel 123
```

So "Cars" is the same like "IDcar"

Now i want to output the right Wheels for every customer.

I already tried the LookupOrderedRow statement but i'm not allowed to save a Field in a variable.

Have any one an idea to output the Wheels?

Later on i want to Preview the Subscriber list, which matched with emails.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* save column values retrieved via AMPScript lookup.  I didn't test this AMPScript, I think you can see how it might work:

```
%%[
var @CustomerRows, @CustomerRow, @CustomerRowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @IDLookupValue, @i, @Cars

set @IDLookupValue = AttributeValue("ID")
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all */
set @CustomerRows = LookupOrderedRows("Customers",@numRowsToReturn,"ID desc, Name asc","ID", @IDLookupValue)
set @CustomerRowCount = rowcount(@CustomerRows)

if @CustomerRowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @CustomerRowCount do

        set @CustomerRow = row(@CustomerRows,@i) 
        set @Cars = field(@CustomerRow,"Cars")

        outputline(concat("<br>CustomerRow ",@i,", ID: ", @IDLookupValue", Cars: ", @Cars))

        set @IDCarLookupValue = @Cars

        var @CarsRow, @CarsRowCount, @j, @wheels

        set @CarsRows = LookupOrderedRows("Cars",@numRowsToReturn,"IDCar desc","IDCar", @IDCarLookupValue)
        set @CarsRowCount = rowcount(@CarsRows)

        if @CarsRowCount > 0 then

            for @j = 1 to @CarsRowCount do

                set @CarsRow = row(@CarsRows,@j) 
                set @Wheels = field(@CarsRow,"Wheels")

                outputline(concat("<br>&nbsp;CarsRow ",@j,", IDCar: ", @IDCarLookupValue", Wheels: ", @Wheels))

            next @j
        else
          outputline(concat("<br>No Cars rows found"))
        endif

   next @i

else
    outputline(concat("<br>No Customer rows found"))
endif

]%%
```

I have a few other AMPScript lookup examples [over here on my blog](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/)...

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime i could solve my problem.

Your code works but only if my Data Extension include a primary key. Without one i do not get any informations back.

So that's was the problem the code not working the whole time.

Thanks again Adam!